# [ios develop]Why does ipad2 camera not full screen?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am using UIImagePickerController to take photo.The process is :

1. start a view with some controls.
2. addsubview on current view:

   self.claim.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 50);
   [self.view addSubview self.claim.view];

3.there is a Button in self.claim.view to start camera and it does start, but the problem is:the vision is only shows in the view area( 0, 0, 1024, 50 ),I can't see anything clear through the camera,why doesn't it fill the screen ?I try several ways but doesn't work.

My tries:
1. set property **cameraOverlayView**(manual said this property set a view to overlay the preview view.)
2. when press the button add another subview with frame(0,0,1024,768), and in new view delegate method***(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated****start the camera.

neither of them is helpful.Is there any possible way to make the camera full screen?

Comment: answered similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606426/camera-has-incorrect-screen-placement-when-open-fullscreen-modal-from-popover
Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. It could be the view controller that you're doing your

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead try to instantiate the imagePicker in another view controller and dismiss the current view controller. Hope this help.