# iPad Camera has incorrect screen placement when you open it

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an iPad app to take a photo or choose from library.
It works fine, the only problem is the camera layout incorrectly when you follow the steps below.

1. List item
2. Tap btnPhotoLibrary button
3. Cancel the popover
4. Tap btnCamera button

The resulting layout is very similar to the image in 
[Camera has incorrect screen placement when open fullscreen modal from popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606426/camera-has-incorrect-screen-placement-when-open-fullscreen-modal-from-popover).

> It is positioned slightly lower than the screen bounds. This means
>   that the controls at the bottom are 20px south of the screen and there
>   is a 20px black band at the top of the screen

You have no problem if you do not tap btnPhotoLibrary but btnCamera only.

We are using the same UIImagePickerController instance for both of camera and photolibrary, so we probably need to reset some properties before using it as a camera, but could not find a way.

--

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = FALSE;
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
}

-(IBAction)btnCamera:(id)sender{
    if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(IBAction)btnPhotoLibrary:(id)sender{
    _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;    
    if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_imagePicker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:btnCameraRoll.bounds inView:btnPhotoLibrary permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
}
```

The target os is iOS6.1, landscape view.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that resetting `view` property of `UIImagePickerController` to `nil` does the trick, but I guess it's almost identical to creating a new instance of `UIImagePickerController` every time you need.

```
-(IBAction)btnCamera:(id)sender{
    if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        _imagePicker.view = nil;
        _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```